# Regex to check if string contains year

Tags: java, regex

I want a regex which matches this year separated with hyphen. Examples

```
1986-2004
2001-2007
```

basically it should allow only 4 digit to each year and not less or more then that and it should be separated with hyphen.

What Regex i tried to build match till 1986-

```
^[0-9]{4}+[-]{1}+[0-9]*$
```

when i try some thing like this

```
^[0-9]{4}+[-]{1}+[0-9]{4}*$
```

{4} at the last year it gives pattern error. Please help me how can i add {4} at the end of the pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` means "any number of times", which clashed with `{4}` which means "four times". Just drop the `*` and you should be OK:

```
^[0-9]{4}+[-]{1}+[0-9]{4}$
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex allows following years too: 8970-9047, 0120-0110, 0000-0000. May be will be better to use the pattern, that will check the boundaries. For example, something like this:

```
\b(18|20)\d{2}\b[-]\b(18|20)\d{2}\b
```